# Code Modification of Existing Access 2007 Macro - Aim to Create & Open (from Access) a New Excel Work-Sheet in Existing Excel 2007 Work-book?

Tags: ms-access, excel-2007, ms-access-2007, vba

Here's the code that makes the new Excel work **book**, but I need the code to create a new work **SHEET** in the same Excel 2007 workbook each time I click the Access 2007 control button. 
Clicking the control button needs to open the Access query and create the Excel work **sheet** and **open** the Excel book/sheet.
The Excel work book must be a macro enabled work book .xlsm format

```
' Command104ContrDonatWeekly_Click
'
'------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub Command104ContrDonatWeekly_Click()
On Error GoTo Command104ContrDonatWeekly_Click_Err

    DoCmd.OpenQuery "Contributors Who Donated in Past Week", acViewNormal, acEdit
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "Contributors Who Donated in Past Week", "ExcelWorkbook(*.xlsx)", "C:\Users\Michael1\Desktop\KSN\DistributionListWeekly.xlsx", True, "", 0, acExportQualityScreen


Command104ContrDonatWeekly_Click_Exit:
    Exit Sub

Command104ContrDonatWeekly_Click_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume Command104ContrDonatWeekly_Click_Exit

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Transferspreadsheet:

```
XLFile = "C:\Docs\MyXLFile.xls"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
    "MyTableOrQuery", XLFile, True, "Sheet2"

FollowHyperlink XLFile

''OR

Shell "Excel.exe " & xlfile, vbNormalFocus
```

Comment: The TransferSpreadsheet method works, but do you have some code that will also **open** the Excel work-book?

Comment: I have added a note on one method.

Comment: Thanks, it works, except one problem is that I get a message that Excel has stopped working and when I select the option to "Check oneline for a solution and close the program", a new Microsoft Office pop-up warning about virus and trust and asking if I wish to open the Excel file, when I click "OK" the Excel file opens and the query data has been imported successfully into a newly created "Sheet 2". Do you have a way to get past this?

Comment: Followhyperlink can cause problems in 2007, I think, so try the shell version above.

Comment: Thanks. It works. Is there any code that will stop the column headings from transferring into the Excel sheet?

Comment: You would need to use automation, which would require quite a bit more code.